# How to convert Unix time?

Tags: javascript, html, unix, unix-timestamp

```
 <el-table-column label="Time Created" prop="create_time"></el-table-column>
```

[image]

The data from the backend is in timestamp format in ms (e.g. 1527150668419) and this.incomeRecordList contains an array of objects with create_time as one of the property. This is what it looks like now, it displays time in seconds and I wish to change the display from seconds to hrs:mins:sec , how do I do that?

This is my script, do I apply the conversion method in here?

```
 getUserIncomeRecordList() {
            Core.Api.User.getUserIncomeRecord(this.userId).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.incomeRecordList = res.record_list;
                console.log(this.incomeRecordList)
            });
```

edit: Thanks Van for helping with elaboration!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to provide more information and data example, e.g. the sample data and what date time string format that you're expecting.
I'm assuming the data from the backend is in timestamp format in ms (e.g. 1527150668419) and `this.incomeRecordList` will contain array of objects with `create_time` as one of the property.

Edit: **Updated the string format to HH:mm:ss** per guymil request

```
getUserIncomeRecordList() {
        Core.Api.User.getUserIncomeRecord(this.userId).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            //apply a mapper here
            this.incomeRecordList = res.record_list.map(a => {
              //get the date object here
              let d = new Date(a.created_time);

              return {
                ...a,
                //format date object to string HH:mm:ss
                created_time:("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
              }
            });
            console.log(this.incomeRecordList)
        });
```

Comment: @guymil have you tried my code above, I have changed the date string format to HH:mm:ss

Comment: Hi @guymil are you still facing the issue? Is there anything else that I can help you with?